# xgboost using R xgb.importance throws error

Tags: r, xgboost

I am using xgboost package from CRAN for the first time.

Creating a model as:

```
bst <- xgb.train(data = dtrain, booster = "gblinear",
 objective = "reg:linear", max.depth = 5, nround = 2,watchlist=watchlist)

importance_matrix <- xgb.importance(model = bst)
```

When I call `xgb.importance` I get an error:

`Error in readLines(filename_dump) : 'con' is not a connection`

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 4):

xgb.importance works fine for booster=gbtree

I did not find any documentation but looks like xgb.importance is valid for tree method only